# Looking up value in JSONField with unaccent and icontains

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Model with a JSONField:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    locale_names = models.JSONField()
```

The shape of the JSON Field is simple: keys are language codes (en, fr...) and values are translated strings.

I'm trying to build a search query that does an unaccented icontains search on a translated value:

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(locale_names__en__unaccent__icontains="Test")
```

This does not give the expected results, because Django interprets "unaccent" as a key to look up in the JSON, rather than the `unaccent` PostgreSQL function:

```sql
-- Expected SQL query: something like
SELECT "app_model"."*" ...
FROM "app_model"
WHERE UPPER(UNACCENT("app_model"."locale_names" ->>'en')::text)) LIKE UPPER(UNACCENT('%Test%'))
LIMIT 21
```

```sql
-- Actual SQL query
SELECT "app_model"."*" ...
FROM "app_model"
WHERE UPPER(("app_model"."locale_names" #>> ARRAY['en','unaccent'])::text) LIKE UPPER('%Test%')
LIMIT 21
```

How can I tel Django to interpret `__unaccent` as the PostgreSQL function rather than a JSON path?

EDIT:

- I'm using Django 3.2
- Doing `__unaccent__icontains` lookups on regular CharFields works as expected.

Comment: Didi you add 'django.contrib.postgres' in your INSTALLED_APPS and activate the unaccent extension on PostgreSQL? (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html)

Comment: @Benbb96 yes. Doing unaccent search on regular CharFields works fine.

Comment: In fact that doesn't seem to be possible on JSONField : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent

Comment: @Benbb96 oh, good catch; and it fails "silently". Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it. I'll write a feature request to the Django team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `JSONField` does not support `unaccent` lookup.

[cf. documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent) :

> The unaccent lookup can be used on CharField and TextField:

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @Benbb96's answer above, my workaround was to write the WHERE clause I needed using the soon-to-be-deprecated [QuerySet.extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method:

```py
MyModel.objects.extra(
    where=[
        "UPPER(UNACCENT((app_model.locale_names->>'en')::text)) LIKE UPPER(UNACCENT(%s))"
    ],
    params=("Test",)
)
```

As requested by the Django team, I created a [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33935#ticket) with them so that this use case can be addressed without `QuerySet.extra()`.